# What is happening when you use the python sleep module?

Tags: python, cron, sleep, schedule

What exactly is happening when I call `time.sleep(5)` in a python script? Is the program using a lot of resources from the computer?

I see people using the `sleep` function in their programs to schedule tasks, but this requires you leave your hard drive running the whole time right? That would be taking for you computer over the long haul right?

I'm trying to figure out what's to run programs at specific times remotely, but I haven't found an explanation of how to do this that is very intuitive.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `sleep` tells the OS to block the process. Nothing happens on the process in the meantime. no cpu is wasted on _that_ process.

Comment: If you are willing to scheluding tasks, check python-crontab.

Answer (score 3):

`sleep` will mark the process (thread) for being inactive until the given time is up.  During this time the kernel will simply not schedule this process (thread).  It will *not* waste resources.

Hard disks typically have spin-down policies based solely on their usage.  If they aren't accessed for a specific time, they will spin down.  They will spin up as soon as some process (thread) is accessing them again.

This means that letting a process (thread) sleep for some time gives the hard disk a chance to spin down (especially if the sleep duration is large, say, more than some minutes).

Comment: "sleep will mark the process (thread) for being inactive until the given time is up" Just a side note to this: `Sleep` will terminate either when the given time is up or when a signal is caught.